# Warning: state has already been added to QState

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm trying to add a state to `QStateMachine` and it gives a warning that

> [20.04 13:31:02 W] QStateMachine::addState: state has already been added to this machine

However, I didn't add the state before, it is the first time. 
Here is my code:

```
idle = new QState();
start_z = new QState();
lock = new QState(); 

m_machine->addState(idle);
m_machine->addState(start_z);
m_machine->addState(lock);
```

Comment: Maybe you call this code twice? Did you debug?

Comment: yes, its only called once. its very weird

Comment: Are you sure its in this part of your code where it happens? If you put debug messages before and after the `m_machine->addState(...)` calls, does the warning message come in between those debug messages?

Comment: yes, whenever I add a state the warning is there, a state has already been added

Comment: Well then you could debug what `idle->machine();` returns before you call `addState`. Do it for each of your states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the easiest way to troubleshoot such warnings.

Go in the class "Qt\5.4\Src\qtbase\src\corelib\statemachine\qstatemachine.cpp", find the method  QStateMachine::addState(QAbstractState *state) and put a breakpoint on the line where it gives the warning. Run your program again and see the stack. It will tell what is going on.

Also it seems all the states are initially the same in your snippet. Define transitions and an initial state as your create the QState and see what happens.